# JSF 2.1 Spring Session Scope

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have the following confguration in my JSF Spring application:

```
<bean id="userSessionBean" class="com.vanilla.beans.UserSessionBean" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
 </bean>
```

Then I ha have Spring bean

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService,Serializable{

@Autowired
    private UserSessionBean userSessionBean;

public String getCurrentUser(){
  return this.userSessionBean.getUserName;
}
}
```

Now I have my managed bean:

@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UserBean {

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{userService}")
    UserService userService;

   public Sttring getUserName(){
    return userService.getCurrentUser();
   }
}
```

then I have xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="#{userBeanBean.userName}" />
```

All my flow works fine, but when my session expires I'm getting the following error and I'm clicking on refresh I have the following stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userSessionBean': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:653)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:604)
    at com.vanilla.beans.UserSessionBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$fe05fe49.getCurrentMokdanName(<generated>)
    at com.vanilla.bl.UserServiceImpl.getCurrentUser(UserServiceImpl.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy18.getCurrentMokedUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.ewave.upromotions.beans.MokedBean.getMokedName(MokedBean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:83)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2400)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2120)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:833)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSession(ServletRequestAttributes.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.getSessionMutex(ServletRequestAttributes.java:211)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    ... 73 more
```

Can I solve it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

To your web.xml

If that will not help please add more info about your web.xml and jsf config.